# JQuery/Javascript calculations with certain if conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery

Iam stuck while doing some calculations in Javascript. I have some rows of records being shown, each rows has calculations. The actual scenario is the system has to calculate quantity * unitprice and fill the total in Total Field. When i change the currency from a dropdown, it has to go through some if conditions which i have given in javascript, its not taking that. Dont know what is the actual issue. Can anyone help? Iam putting the html form below:

```
   <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js'></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">

 function isNum(value)
 {
return 123;
 }

 function calcTotals()
 {
   var total = 0;
var i = 0;

while (document.forms['cart'].elements['unitprice[]'][i])
{
    unitpriceObj = document.forms['cart'].elements['unitprice[]'][i];
    item_quantityObj   = document.forms['cart'].elements['item_quantity[]'][i];
    total_inr_valueObj   = document.forms['cart'].elements['total_inr[]'][i];

    totalObj = document.forms['cart'].elements['total[]'][i];


    totalObj.value = parseFloat((item_quantityObj.value*1) * unitpriceObj.value*1);

        //Currency_change formulae
        var e = document.getElementById("currency_change[]");
        var currency_selected = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        var price = $(this).find(':selected').data('price');

        if (currency_selected.value() == 'INR'){ 
            total_inr_valueObj.value=totalObj.value;
                } else if (currency_selected.value() == 'USD'){ 
            total_inr_valueObj.value = totalObj.value * price.value;
            } else {
            total_inr_valueObj.value = (inrvalue.value / price.value) * totalObj.value;
            }
    }

    i++;
}
return;
 }

 </script>


 </head>
 <body>

 <form name='cart' method='post' class='single' action='generate_quot_cust_edititems_save_complete.php?tender_id=1' >

     <table width="100%" border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
     <tr bgcolor="#E6E6FA">
     <td width=4%>SlNo</td>
     <td width=10%>Item Name</td>
<td width=4%>Qty</td>
<td width=3%>Units</td>
<td width=4%>Unitprice</td>
<td width=6%>Currency</td>
<td width=6%>Total</td>
<td width=6%>Total INR</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width='4%'>
<input size='1' type='hidden' name='id[0]' value='' readonly/>
<input size='1' type='text' name='sl[0]' value='1' readonly/>
</td>
<td width='10%'><input type='text' size='28' id='item_name0' name='item_name[0]' placeholder='filter 3' value='filter 3' /</td>
<td width='4%'><input size='1' class='item_quantity' type='text' name='item_quantity[]' id='item_quantity[]' value='25' /></td>
<td width='3%'><input size='1' class='item_units' type='text' name='item_units[]' id='item_units[]' value='Nos' readonly/></td>
<td width='4%'><input size='5' class='unitprice' type='text' name='unitprice[]' id='unitprice[]' value='' onchange='calcTotals()'/></td>
<td width='6%'>
<select id='currency_change[]' name='currency_change[]'>
<option value=''>select</option>
<option  value=USD data-price=1>USD</option>
<option  value=INR data-price=65.831111>INR</option>
<option  value=GBP data-price=0.643864>GBP</option>
<option  value=EUR data-price=0.88469>EUR</option>
<option  value=SGD data-price=1.398912>SGD</option>
</select></td>
<td width='8%'><input size='9' type='text' name='total[]' id='total[]' value='' readonly class='total'/></td>
<td width='8%'><input size='7' type='text' id='total_inr[]' name='total_inr[]' value=''/></td>
</tr>
     <tr>
     <td width='4%'><input size='1' type='hidden' name='id[1]' value='' readonly/><input size='1' type='text' name='sl[1]' value='2' readonly/></td>
<td width='10%'><input type='text' size='28' id='item_name1' name='item_name[1]' placeholder='Filter2' value='Filter2' /</td>
<td width='4%'><input size='1' class='item_quantity' type='text' name='item_quantity[]' id='item_quantity[]' value='15' /></td>
<td width='3%'><input size='1' class='item_units' type='text' name='item_units[]' id='item_units[]' value='Nos' readonly/></td>
<td width='4%'><input size='5' class='unitprice' type='text' name='unitprice[]' id='unitprice[]' value='' onchange='calcTotals()'/></td>
<td width='6%'>
<select id='currency_change[]' name='currency_change[]'>
<option value=''>select</option>
<option  value=USD data-price=1>USD</option>
<option  value=INR data-price=65.831111>INR</option>
<option  value=GBP data-price=0.643864>GBP</option>
<option  value=EUR data-price=0.88469>EUR</option>
<option  value=SGD data-price=1.398912>SGD</option>
</select>
</td>

<td width='8%'><input size='9' type='text' name='total[]' id='total[]' value='' readonly class='total'/></td>
<td width='8%'><input size='7' type='text' id='total_inr[]' name='total_inr[]' value=''/></td>
</tr>

 </table></div>    
<br><br>INR Value -><input type="text" class="inrvalue" id="inrvalue" name="inrvalue" value="65.831111">
 <br><br>

 <table><td><input type='submit' value='--Save Data--' /></td></tr></table></form>
```

Comment: what is `add_percentageObj`

Comment: demo: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xdrLm5ao/

Comment: I have removed add_percentageObj. Its is for some other calculations. I have updated the script

Comment: Is the script working?

Comment: what is `inrvalue.value`

Comment: This is actually a php script. Iam getting the INR Value from the database. I have put the value in the html just to show the value of inr.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xdrLm5ao/2/ ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xdrLm5ao/3/ ?

Comment: It is working fine, but there is a small mistake in the javascript the last condition.  } else {
        $totInr.val((inr/ unitprice) * total);
    }...... here its should be ((inr/price) *total);.....This price has to come from the data-price..which i have included in my drop down. For Ex:     <option value=GBP data-price=0.643864>GBP</option>...so as per the currency selected from the dropdown, it has to calculate the price.

Comment: see the updated answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your script.

A more jQuery-ish solution will be something like

```js
$('#table :input').change(function() {
  var $tr = $(this).closest('tr'),
    $totInr = $tr.find('[name="total_inr[]"]'),
    unitprice = +$tr.find('[name="unitprice[]"]').val() || 0,
    qty = +$tr.find('[name="item_quantity[]"]').val() || 0,
    $currency = $tr.find('[name="currency_change[]"] option:selected'),
    currency = $currency.val(),
    inr = $('#inrvalue').val();

  var total = unitprice * qty;
  $tr.find('[name="total[]"]').val(total);

  if (currency == 'INR') {
    $totInr.val(total);
  } else if (currency == 'USD') {
    $totInr.val(total * unitprice);
  } else {
    $totInr.val((inr / ($currency.data('price') || 1)) * total);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name='cart' method='post' class='single' action='generate_quot_cust_edititems_save_complete.php?tender_id=1'>
  <table width="100%" border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" id="table">
    <tr bgcolor="#E6E6FA">
      <td width=4%>SlNo</td>
      <td width=10%>Item Name</td>
      <td width=4%>Qty</td>
      <td width=3%>Units</td>
      <td width=4%>Unitprice</td>
      <td width=6%>Currency</td>
      <td width=6%>Total</td>
      <td width=6%>Total INR</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width='4%'>
        <input size='1' type='hidden' name='id[0]' value='' readonly/>
        <input size='1' type='text' name='sl[0]' value='1' readonly/>
      </td>
      <td width='10%'>
        <input type='text' size='28' id='item_name0' name='item_name[0]' placeholder='filter 3' value='filter 3' /</td>
        <td width='4%'>
          <input size='1' class='item_quantity' type='text' name='item_quantity[]' value='25' />
        </td>
        <td width='3%'>
          <input size='1' class='item_units' type='text' name='item_units[]' id='item_units[]' value='Nos' readonly/>
        </td>
        <td width='4%'>
          <input size='5' class='unitprice' type='text' name='unitprice[]' id='unitprice[]' value='' />
        </td>
        <td width='6%'>
          <select id='currency_change[]' name='currency_change[]'>
            <option value=''>select</option>
            <option value=USD data-price=1>USD</option>
            <option value=INR data-price=65.831111>INR</option>
            <option value=GBP data-price=0.643864>GBP</option>
            <option value=EUR data-price=0.88469>EUR</option>
            <option value=SGD data-price=1.398912>SGD</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td width='8%'>
          <input size='9' type='text' name='total[]' id='total[]' value='' readonly class='total' />
        </td>
        <td width='8%'>
          <input size='7' type='text' id='total_inr[]' name='total_inr[]' value='' />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width='4%'>
        <input size='1' type='hidden' name='id[1]' value='' readonly/>
        <input size='1' type='text' name='sl[1]' value='2' readonly/>
      </td>
      <td width='10%'>
        <input type='text' size='28' id='item_name1' name='item_name[1]' placeholder='Filter2' value='Filter2' /</td>
        <td width='4%'>
          <input size='1' class='item_quantity' type='text' name='item_quantity[]' id='item_quantity[]' value='15' />
        </td>
        <td width='3%'>
          <input size='1' class='item_units' type='text' name='item_units[]' id='item_units[]' value='Nos' readonly/>
        </td>
        <td width='4%'>
          <input size='5' class='unitprice' type='text' name='unitprice[]' id='unitprice[]' value='' />
        </td>
        <td width='6%'>
          <select id='currency_change[]' name='currency_change[]'>
            <option value=''>select</option>
            <option value=USD data-price=1>USD</option>
            <option value=INR data-price=65.831111>INR</option>
            <option value=GBP data-price=0.643864>GBP</option>
            <option value=EUR data-price=0.88469>EUR</option>
            <option value=SGD data-price=1.398912>SGD</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td width='8%'>
          <input size='9' type='text' name='total[]' id='total[]' value='' readonly class='total' />
        </td>
        <td width='8%'>
          <input size='7' type='text' id='total_inr[]' name='total_inr[]' value='' />
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>INR Value ->
  <input type="text" class="inrvalue" id="inrvalue" name="inrvalue" value="65.831111">
  <br>
  <br>
  <table>
    <td>
      <input type='submit' value='--Save Data--' />
    </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanx a lot Arun.. Taking for your time. Its is working fine now.

Comment: @SujithNair assigned an id to the table `id="table"` - and removed the `onchnage=""` attribute

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use AngularJS Numbers:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="" ng-init="quantity=1;cost=5">
  <p>Total in dollar: {{ quantity * cost }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I have not worked in Angular Js. So not sure about that.

Comment: AngularJS is much easier, it take no time to make such a code